# how to split a html page based on the presence of <p> <div> or <br> tags

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to split scraped webpages into distinct parts on the basis of the position of
`<p>` `<br>` or `<div>` tags. So the first `<p>` tag would contain all the data/tags from `<html>` to the `<p>` tag in question. I have looked at something like etree from the lxml project, but it looks tangential.

The difference i see from "normal" html parsing is the number of tags selected. I want to select multiple tags and their data and save them seperately while "normal" html parsing tools offer the ability to select only one isolated tag/tags (using xpath,etc) and play with it. (I am also pretty new to web programming).

I have thought of a way where i would save file offsets and then proceed to cut and slice the input file to achieve my goal, but it seems hackish at best.

How can i go about achieving my stated goal, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: beautifulsoup would be a good tool to use

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but what should i use in beautiful soup. Could you be more specific on how i can save parts of the html tree to separate files

Answer (score 3):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). It's a great python tool for parsing HTML.

Below is an example to show how easy it is to parse HTML - it prints the tag name (p) and the contents of all the `<p>` tags. Then it finds the element with id of "header".

This is just a snippet - BeautifulSoup provides many ways to filter HTML documents.

```
import sys
# add path to beautifulsoup library
sys.path.append('/usr/local/var/beautifulsoup')
# import it
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("yourfile.html"))
for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    print tag.name, tag.text

soup.find(id="header")
```